# Rows As Series Plotly R

Tags: r, plotly, r-plotly

I have a dataframe:

```
df<-data.frame(Level=c("Small","Bigger","Biggest"),Threshold1=c(0.9,.8,.7),Threshold2=c(0.4,.5,.6),Threshold3=c(.6,.2,.1))
```

I want to produce a graphic as below, but using plotly:

[image]

How would you read this in to plotly and make this happen?

I have tried rotating using t() and looked at plotly documentation, but didn't see anything about a means to use rows as series and the value of an identifier column as series name.

In my real-life data, the number of values that can exist in the `Level` column can change, so ideally I would like to find a solution that can scale with whatever number of values `Level` may consist of.

Any help is much appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is easier if you use data.table:

```
library(data.table)
library(plotly
df<-data.table(Level=c("Small","Bigger","Biggest"),Threshold1=c(0.9,.8,.7),Threshold2=c(0.4,.5,.6),Threshold3=c(.6,.2,.1))

d <-melt.data.table(df, id.vars='Level')
plot_ly(d, x=~variable, y=~value,type = 'scatter', mode = 'lines',  color = ~Level)
```

You should obtain the desired chart.
[image: Chart]

Answer (score 0):

Solution in base R:

```
library(plotly)

df<-data.frame(Level=c("Small","Bigger","Biggest"),
               Threshold1=c(0.9,.8,.7),Threshold2=c(0.4,.5,.6),Threshold3=c(.6,.2,.1))

df.reshaped <- reshape(df, varying = c("Threshold1", "Threshold2", "Threshold3"), 
                            v.names = "Values", idvar = "Level", direction = "long", 
                            times = c("Threshold1", "Threshold2", "Threshold3"), 
                            new.row.names = 1:(3 * nrow(df)))

plot_ly(df.reshaped, x=~time, y=~Values, type = 'scatter', mode = 'lines',  color = ~Level)
```

Output plot:

[image]